# Limiting query for one result where there is 2 values are matching

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to query 2 long columns for agents' name, the issue is the names are repeated on 2 tables, one for the total sum of productivity and the other is for total sum of utilization.

The thing is when I query the columns it returns back the numbers for Productivity and Utilization all together.

How can I make the query to search only for Productivity alone and for Utilization alone?

Link is here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12Sydw6ejFobySHUj5JoYkAPbhr0mKoInCWxtHY1W4lk/edit#gid=0

Comment: Hi, is your issue fixed? Because I see both Productivity and Utilisation values in different cells.

Comment: No sadly, its just the normal query. i need a single formula for Productivity and Utilization.

Comment: Ok, I also see that these tables are repeated consecutively. I guess you want each formula to search on all of them, differentiating Productivity and Utilisation, right? This would be much simpler if they were on different Columns instead of being in the same one. Otherwise Apps Script would be the best solution here.

Comment: Yes you got me right. too bad i dont have that good experience in coding to start with Apps Scripts. Do you have any learning resources for a very noob level for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apps Script would be a better solution in this case. The code below works as follows:

1. Gets the names from Column D and Column A.
2. For each name of Column D, it will compare it with each name of Column A (that's the 2 [for loops](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp))
3. If the names coincide (first [if](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp)), it will check the background color (second if) of the Column A name to accumulate Total Prod and Total Util.
4. Once it reaches the end of the Column A, writes the values in Total Prod and Total Util (Columns E and F) for each name in D.

```
function onOpen() { //Will run every time you open the sheet

  //Gets the active Spreadsheet and sheet
  let sprsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let sheet = sprsheet.getActiveSheet();

  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

  var getNames = sheet.getRange(3, 1, lastRow).getValues(); //Names from row 2, col 1, until the last row
  var totalNames = sheet.getRange("D4:D5").getValues(); //Change the range for more names

  let prodColor = '#f2f4f7'; //hexadecimal codes of the background colors of names in A
  let utilColor = '#cfe2f3'; //

  for (var i = 0; i < totalNames.length; i++) {

    var totalProd = 0, totalUtil = 0; //Starts at 0 for each name in D

    for (var j = 0; j < getNames.length; j++) {

      if (totalNames[i][0] == getNames[j][0]) {

        if (sheet.getRange(j + 3, 1).getBackgroundObject().asRgbColor().asHexString() == prodColor) { //if colors coincide

          totalProd += sheet.getRange(j + 3, 2).getValue();

        } else if (sheet.getRange(j + 3, 1).getBackgroundObject().asRgbColor().asHexString() == utilColor) {

          totalUtil += sheet.getRange(j + 3, 2).getValue();

        }        
      }      
    }
    sheet.getRange(i+4, 5, 1 ,2).setValues([[totalProd, totalUtil]]);

  }  
}
```

> Note: You will have to run the code manually and accept permissions the first time you run it. After that it will run automatically each time you open the Sheet. It might take a few seconds for the code to run and to reflect changes on the Sheet.

To better understand loops and 2D arrays, I recommend you to take a look at [this](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-multidimensional-array/).

**References**:

- [Range Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)
- [Get Values](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [Get BackgroundObject](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getbackgroundobject)
- [Set Values](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

You can learn more about Apps Script and Sheets by following the [Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/apps-script).

Comment: Thank you so much Jescanelles <3